# Are same row pixels exposed simultaneously for rolling shutter sensor in ERS mode?

Tags: timing, image-sensor

I know that each pixel row in a rolling shutter sensor running in ERS mode (Electronic Rolling Shutter) are exposed for the same duration but at different points in time. But what about each pixel in the same row? Do they also differ slightly in when they are exposed or are all pixels in a row exposed simultaneously?

Comment: Do you have a specific image sensor in mind, or is this a generic question if rolling shutter works per-pixel or per-row or if both types exist?

Comment: @Justme It was a general question, but if both types exist I would also like to know which type the AR0521 sensor belongs to. https://www.onsemi.com/products/sensors/image-sensors/ar0521

Comment: the datasheet is not publicly available and even if it were it likely does not contain that detail. You need to ask the manufacturer.

Comment: Datasheet does not mention this. I have raised the question on On-Semis support forum.

Comment: Got the answer: For this particular sensor they are exposed simultaneously in ERS mode.